# how to fetch blob from database mysql in jdbc

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

@Override
    public LinkedList getRoomsDetails(String Id) {

```
    System.out.println("entering into getting room details");
    LinkedList<RoomDetails> list=new LinkedList<RoomDetails>();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"j2ee","tiger");
        query="select * from roomDetails where hotelId="+"'"+Id+"'";
        stmt=con.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            RoomDetails room=new RoomDetails();
            room.setHotelId(rs.getString("hotelId"));
            room.setRoomId(rs.getString("roomId"));
            room.setRoomNo(rs.getString("roomNo"));
            room.setRoomType(rs.getString("roomType"));
            room.setPerNightRate(rs.getString("perNightRate"));
            room.setAvailability(rs.getString("availability"));
            room.setImage( (InputStream) rs.getBlob("image"));
            list.add(room);

        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Unable to fetch blob using from my sql ... altough i was able to  insert using inputstream

Comment: what is the type of image defined in the model?

Comment: What, in the javadoc of ResultSet.getBlob(), makes you think that it's a correct thing to cact what it returns to InputStream? Have you read the javadoc of this method? Have you read the javadoc of the class returned by this method? Just doing that would fix your problem, in a small fraction of time it takes to write this question. Read the documentation. That's why it's been written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use getBinaryStream() which is returning InputStream

```
room.setImage = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
```

Comment: Exception is removed now. thanks for this. This InputStream object object i m passing to servlet by storing in RoomDetails object. and then i m trying to display it in jsp. Can you please tell me how to display it through jsp.